# Why do i get Undefined when i try to populate this literal template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, literals

I set a local storage item, an array to be more accurate.

Then I get it and try to populate my literal template but I get an undefined

> undefined:1 GET http://localhost/undefined 404 (Not Found) on
>   undefined:1

Here's my code:

```
var rawRelatedProductCategoryArray = localStorage.getItem('relatedCategoryProductsSelected');

var parsedRelatedProductArray = ('rawRelatedProductCategoryArray', JSON.parse(rawRelatedProductCategoryArray));

console.log(parsedRelatedProductArray); // on this i get the result of my array

document.getElementById("relatedProducts").innerHTML = `${parsedRelatedProductArray.map(relatedProductsTemplate).join('')}`
```

Here's the template i'm trying to put the array data in it:

```
function relatedProductsTemplate(relatedProduct) {
  return `
   <div class="relatedDiv">
    <div class="item mb-0 text-center ">
      <div>
        <div class="post-prev-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="${relatedProduct.image}" alt="img"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="post-prev-title mb-5">
          <h3><a class="font-norm a-inv" href="shop-single.html">${relatedProduct.dataProduct}</a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="shop-price-cont">
          <strong>${relatedProduct.price}</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
}
```

Comment: Where does that URL come from?

Comment: Can you show the content of `parsedRelatedProductArray` ?

Comment: You mean this one? http://localhost/undefined

Comment: 0: [{category: "analysis", dataProduct: "Mettler JL603-C - ZY5030", image: "images/used/jl603-c.jpg",…},…]
0: {category: "analysis", dataProduct: "Mettler JL603-C - ZY5030", image: "images/used/jl603-c.jpg",…}
1: {category: "analysis", dataProduct: "Mettler JS-2002-G - BL292002", image: "images/used/js2002-g.jpg",…}
2: {category: "analysis", dataProduct: "OHAUS SPU6001 - BL8060", image: "images/used/spu6001.jpg",…}
@R3tep

Comment: Maybe there is a product without image ?

Comment: I use the same array but not filtred in another page an i got all the urls correct and all the images.

Comment: @McMazalf I try your code with the array given and it's working :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i did wrong:

the problem was because the array was nested.

So i did like this :

```
  var arrayNesting = parsedRelatedProductArray[0];
```

Then i've passed the var to the literal like this:

```
  document.getElementById("relatedProducts").innerHTML =
    `${arrayNesting.map(relatedProductsTemplate).join('')}`
```